# how to I upload image file after snap with ftp in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

from online research, there are few solution using base64 and post into database. but it make database become slower and may be will jam. I willing to know how to upload image file after snap by using ftp

Comment: the path may like something like this ftp:\\103.1.11.123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think decode image to `base64` is bad idea. Maybe using this [ftpconnect](https://pub.dev/packages/ftpconnect) you can more efficiently upload your image. Instead decode it into `base64` you can directly get `File` from the image path. Thank you

Comment: now my question is how to upload picture(image picker) after ftp connect  success